# API Data SSL Certificate Issue

Tags: p5.js

I have created a program in p5.js that takes weather data from an API and visualizes it. This code works fine on my website when not secure (HTTP), but fails to work when secured (HTTPS). Is there any reason/solution for this?

```
 var weather;

var api = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=';
var apiKey = '&APPID=021d86e44b1e37bd28f27baf523d920a';
var units = '&units=imperial';
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
      var button = select('#submit');
  button.mousePressed(weatherAsk);
  input = select('#city');ff

}

function weatherAsk() {
  var url = api + input.value() + apiKey + units;
  loadJSON(url, gotData);
}

function gotData(data) {
  weather = data;
}

function draw(){
  background(255);


  if (weather){
        var temp = map(weather.main.temp, 32, 110, 0, 255);
        var wind = map(weather.wind.speed, 0, 100, 0, 255);
        var humid = map(weather.main.humidity, 0, 100, 0, 255)
        var see = map(weather.visibility, 0, 29000, 0, 255)
      noStroke();

    fill(temp);
    rect(0,0, 200,200)
    fill(wind)
    rect(200,0,200,200)
    fill(humid)
    rect(0,200,200,200)
    fill(see)
    rect(200,200,200,200)
    fill(255)
    textStyle(ITALIC)
    textAlign(CENTER);
     textSize(10)
     fill(temp-255);
     text("temperature",100,100)
      fill(255)
    text("wind speed", 300, 100)
      fill(255)
      text("humidity", 100,300)
      fill(255)
      text("visibility", 300,300)
  }

}
```

Comment: Please check [the JavaScript console](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools) for errors.

Comment: *fails to work* is not a useful problem description. You've not given any information about what *fails* means. No logs, no console messages, no description of any issues at all. If you don't understand why that's not useful, try calling your auto repair shop and saying *My car's making a funny noise, but I'm not going to tell you more. I emailed you a picture to show you what it looks like. What's wrong with it and how much will it cost to fix?* and see if they'll give you a diagnosis and estimate.

Comment: Okay I understand: https://imgur.com/a/E0CPi here's the console errors, thank you

Comment: @DoLi Don't tell **us** the errors. You need to take those errors and try to understand them. If you're still having trouble, please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @DoLi Actually those don't look like errors. Try checking the network tab. Is something failing to load?

Comment: @DoLi Is that you actual API key on line 3? Might want to take it out of the example...?